# use after free vulnerability

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability

I am struggling trying to understand use after free vulnerabilities, can someone explain it for me with C language source code, and how it can be used to write to arbitary memory location or to cause code execution

Comment: What about [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_after_free#Cause_of_dangling_pointers)?